# How to cast a method on an object that is not declared yet

Tags: java, object, oop, methods, types

I am planning to call a method of an object, which is currently not initialized. I have created an object of the appropriate type in my Main method (code is below) (called line) and now want to call a method in another class with this object. However, I get the message "line cannot be resolved".

I have already tried to declare the object directly in the corresponding class, but then I get a NullPointerException. If I initialize the class there, I don't know how to get it back into my other class to the main method, since it is needed there to initialize another object.

```
public class Turtle {
    
    TurtleState state;
    LineFrame lineframe;

    public Turtle(LineFrame lineFrame) {
        this(lineFrame, 0.5, 0.5, Math.PI / 2);
    }
    public Turtle(LineFrame lineFrame, double initX, double initY, double initAngle) {
        
        state = new TurtleState(initX, initY, initAngle, false);
        

    }
    public void forward(double stepSize) {
        
        if(state.getDown() == true) {
            
            lineframe.drawLine(0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5);
            
        }
    }
public class Cube {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
        LineFrame line = new LineFrame("Test");
        Turtle turtle = new Turtle(line);
        turtle.penDown();
        turtle.forward(0.5);    
    }

}
public class LineFrame {
...
    public void drawLine(double x0, double y0, double x1, double y1) {
        synchronized(pathList) {
            if (currentPathLength > MAXIMUM_PATH_LENGTH) {
                currentPathLength = 0;
                pathList.add(0, new Path2D.Double());
            } else {
                ++currentPathLength;
            }
            Path2D path = pathList.get(0);  
            path.moveTo(x0, y0);
            path.lineTo(x1, y1);
        }
        drawPanel.repaint();
    }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second constructor of `Turtle`, add the assignment of `lineFrame` to the instance field:

```
public Turtle(LineFrame lineFrame, double initX, double initY, double initAngle) {
    
    state = new TurtleState(initX, initY, initAngle, false);
    this.lineFrame = lineFrame; // add this line

}
```

In your original code, you passed the `lineFrame` object into the constructor but did not assign it to the instance variable. Hence when you called the `forward()` method, it threw the error because the variable was not pointing to any object.